# How to make a numpy array of form ([1.], [2.], [3.]...) from list?

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to make a numpy array of the form `([1.], [2.], ...)` from a list `[1, 2, 3]` so I can use it as an input for `sklearn's linear_model`.

This command

```
np.array(test_list)
```

produces this kind of array:

```
array([1, 2, 3, 4])
```

whereas I want

```
array ([1], [2], [3], [4])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just reshape:

```
 import  numpy as np

arr = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])

print(arr.reshape(arr.size, 1).astype(float))
```

Which would give you:

```
[[ 1.]
[ 2.]
[ 3.]
[ 4.]
[ 5.]]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can insert a new axis and transpose:

```
>>> arr = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4], dtype=float)
>>> arr[None, ...].T
array([[1.],
       [2.],
       [3.],
       [4.]])
```

As with most things `numpy`, there's probably a better way, but this works alright :-).

Or, as pointed out in the comments, you can just insert an axis at the right place:

```
>>> arr[..., None]
array([[ 1.],
       [ 2.],
       [ 3.],
       [ 4.]])
```

Note that you could write `None` as `np.newaxis` if you find that to be more semantically correct.

Comment: `arr[:, None]` is a bit simpler

Comment: @hpaulj -- Yep, so it is.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

+1 to mgilson's answer. Here's another way:

```
arr = np.array([np.array([float(i)]) for i in test_list])
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also use NumPy's [`atleast_2d`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.atleast_2d.html) and transpose:

```
In [270]: np.atleast_2d([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]).T.astype(float)
Out[270]: 
array([[ 1.],
       [ 2.],
       [ 3.],
       [ 4.],
       [ 5.]])
```

Comment: thanks a lot. It's helpful to know there's such a specialized function!